# How do I convert Google fonts .ttf file to other file to types to support all the browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I am going to use 'Open Sans' font. I downloaded the pack from google fonts directory. It has only ttf  format files. I want all the file formats(EOT, SVG, WOFF) to support all browser. How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not provide the other formats but neither you need to convert them yourself. You can download all font formats including X-Browser-CSS at http://localfont.com/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot');
  src: url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Open Sans'),
       local('Open-Sans-regular'),
       url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff') format('woff'),
       url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3Zbd9NUM7myrQQz30yPaGQ4&skey=62c1cbfccc78b4b2&v=v13#OpenSans') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i always use this sites
[first](http://transfonter.org/)
[second](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)
[third](https://everythingfonts.com/font-face)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft [Web Embedding Fonts Tool (WEFT)](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/WEFT.mspx). It helps you create EOT objects.

As for the Open Sans, you can go back to the Google Fonts website and acquire a link for embedding it into your website.

1. In the old Google Font website (google.com/font), find the font and press the "Quick-use" button. There is an "Add this code to your website" section.
2. In the newer Google Font website (fonts.google.com), type the font's name in the search box and press Enter. Find the font in the list and hover you mouse over it. Select the style that you want. (Regular, bold, etc.) Click on plus sign link to upper right corner of the font sample. Repeat this step for the other styles that you want. Click on the popup that appears at the bottom of the screen.

It gave me this code:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Just open [the link that I gave you](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,700italic) in a browser window. You will find download URLs there. You need to do some copying and pasting but that's nothing hard, I imagine.